# mui-x datagrid: how to make a custom singleSelect like 'country-column'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm looking for an example-code how to make a singleSelect with icons in the column and the select-options like in the Country-Column at the filterling-section-site on the [datagrid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/). Here is a pic:

[image: single-select-column with icons]

Am I too stupid to use google or is it really hard to find the code of this country-example on the [mui-homepage](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/)?

Comment: On every MUI example there is a SANDBOX and code, just click the buttons below the example

Comment: @todevv thanks I already know that but this piece of code is encapsulated in some internal mui-x datagrid libs which is a huge disadvantage in my opinion. Everything else is well documented in small pieces of code except this usecase

Comment: You will find all the code of the encapsulated mui-x datagrid at https://github.com/mui/mui-x/tree/master/packages/grid/x-data-grid-generator